# How do I access a EBS volume that I've created on a EC2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have created a EBS volume on /dev/sdh like so:

```
 $ ec2-attach-volume -d /dev/sdh -i i-7058e010 vol-58f08432
ATTACHMENT  vol-58f08432    i-7058e010  /dev/sdh    attaching   2011-09-19T12:48:01+0000
```

Following this tutorial http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663, I am now trying to "Create an XFS file system on the EBS volume"

But when I try to do that I get:

```
root@ip-10-100-254-47:~# sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdh
/dev/sdh: No such file or directory
```

When I look at the EBS volume in the console it seems to be working properly:

```
Attachment:
i-7058e010:/dev/sdh (attached)
```

EDIT: this instance is not an EBS store instance, does that mean I can't use EBS with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should actually work, unless your instance `i-7058e010` does not correspond to  `ip-10-100-254-47`.

Try `partprobe` and `blkid` inside your instance to see whether you can find out more information/force rescanning the bus.

> EDIT: this instance is not an EBS store instance, does that mean I can't use EBS with it?

No, whether you are using EBS root or regular S3 manifests ami doesn't have anything to do with the ability to attach EBS volumes.

---

PS. if you are trying to do XFS because of xfs_freeze,xfs_unfreeze (*consistent snapshotting*) be advised that recent kernels support the same controls for ext4 just fine.

Comment: @sehe.. so you mean if I use consistent snapshotting like as explained under [ec2-consistent-snapshot](http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2011/05/ec2-consistent-snapshot-on-amazons-linux-ami/), it doesn't need to be done with a XFS formatted volume, but could be done via a regular ext volume?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that /dev/sdh doesn't exist on Ubuntu Natty.  I had to use /dev/sdf which maps to /dev/xvdf on the actual server.

Comment: eeee - you should report that to canonical/alestic (http://alestic.com/ or the http://groups.google.com/group/ec2ubuntu list). That would be a stopper for big-data computing - I frequently have done dozens of EBS volumes in raid to get some tests done)

Comment: aw.... unless you meant you needed to say xvdh :) Shame on me, I _knew_ that but it didn't cross my mind when typing